# Return value from Antlr rule required to be of *Context type?

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm refreshing my Antlr skills (after a long hiatus), with Antlr 4, and I have a rule that looks like:

```
filterExpression returns [ActivityPredicate pred]: NAME OPERATOR NUMBER {
    return new SingleActivityPredicate($NAME.text, Operator.fromCharacter($OPERATOR.text), $NUMBER.text);
};
```

Where `SingleActivityPredicate` is a class I wrote that implements my `ActivityPredicate` interface.

But the generated method in the parser is:

```
public final FilterExpressionContext filterExpression() throws RecognitionException {
```

And as a result, understandably, the parser has a syntax error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from SingleActivityPredicate to PredicatesParser.FilterExpressionContext
```

How can I allow my rule to return a custom data type that is *not* of the `<RuleName>Context`?

Finding examples of Antlr grammars that use embedded Java code has been a bit tricky, so if anyone has any recommended reading/resources, I would happily accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to `return` anything explicitly, rather assign the variable name of the returned item:

```
filterExpression returns [ActivityPredicate pred]: NAME OPERATOR NUMBER {
    $pred = new SingleActivityPredicate($NAME.text, Operator.fromCharacter($OPERATOR.text), $NUMBER.text);
};
```